# Spring boot security post request not working with cors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, cors

I'm using the spring boot framework, I have implemented two rest endpoints type get and type post requests.
Get and post requests are working fine if we access those ends from the same origin.
When I'm trying to access those endpoints from react application, the Get request is working fine but when I hit the second endpoint (post request) getting status code 401. I couldn't find any cors error in browser console
Front end code.

```
const _HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-xsrf-token': getCSRFToken(),
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("admin" + ":" + "admin")
}

let fetchData = async  (resource:string, method:string, postData:Object, mode:string = _SAME_ORGIN, formData:any = null, headers:any = _HEADERS ) => {
    let initObj = {};
    if( method === "GET" ) {
        initObj = {
            method: method,
            mode: mode,
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: headers
          };
    } else {
        initObj = {
            method: method,
            mode: mode,
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: headers,
            body: formData === null? JSON.stringify(postData): formData
        };
    }
    
    return await fetch( new Request(resource, initObj) );
}
```

Backend code

```
Global cors
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer configure() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void  addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                Boolean corsEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean( environment.getProperty("application.cors.enabled"));
                if( corsEnabled != null && corsEnabled == true ) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8000");
                }
            }
        };
    }

Security
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()) 
        .and().authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.formLogin();
        http.httpBasic();
        if (corsEnabled != null && corsEnabled == true) {
            http.cors();
        }
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are _response_ headers, not _request_ headers. Take the time to read and understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the post request not working". Provide more details. Do you observe a CORS error in your browser's Console tab? If so, what does the error message say?

Comment: rest end point,  method type POST. getting status code 401.
I couldn't find any cors errors.

Comment: *CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies*. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html

Comment: Need more details of security configuration. 401 means unauthorized error. So it has to do with your basic auth or the way you configured end point security configurations.

Answer (score -1):

Update security.

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.formLogin();
        http.httpBasic();
        if (corsEnabled != null && corsEnabled == true) {
            http.cors();
        }
```